# Lagrangian of $LC$ oscillator: where is encoded the fact that ($U$, $Q$) and ($U$,$\dot{I}$) are proportional?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

Consider an L.C circuit with no driving.

The equation of motion is, with $\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$

$$ \ddot{Q}+\frac{1}{\omega_0^2} Q = 0$$

We can show that the following Lagrangian correctly describes the dynamic:

$$\mathcal{L}(Q,\dot{Q})=\frac{L\dot{Q}^2}{2}-\frac{Q^2}{2 C}$$

My question is the following:

I agree that this Lagrangian is a good one in the sense we will find the E.O.M from Euler Lagrange equation.

However what disturbs me is: **how can I know that the voltage around capacitor and inductance will be $U=Q/C=L \ddot{Q}$**. If the Lagrangian is supposed to contain all the dynamic, this information must be inside.

One could say that **by definition** of $C$, we have $C=\frac{Q}{U}$ (same idea for $L$), but what disturbs me is that, as $C$ is a constant, it is not simply a definition, it also means that in the dynamic $Q$ and $U$ are proportional. Thus there is some physical information in it.

Which point am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

This description by itself doesn't have enough information to define the voltage of anything. I mean, if you're just given $\mathcal{L} = L \dot{Q}^2/2 - Q^2/2C$ in isolation, you don't even know that $Q$ represents an electric charge, much less an electric charge on a capacitor in a circuit containing only a capacitor and inductor. All of this is additional structure you have to put in separately.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. Actually my problem is more complicated than this one, I thought this example was a "minimal working example" of what causes me problem but probably not (even if something still disturbs me in your answer but I have to properly formalize my problem, I am a little confused). My actual, more specific problem is the following: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529766/quantization-of-a-waveguide-he-only-has-one-of-the-two-e-o-m-in-his-lagrangian

Comment: @StarBucK Well, first off, do you believe that this answer resolves your simplified question?

Comment: Not totally, I have to think more closely of how to formulate what disturbs me. Things are confused in my mind. But my other problem is I think different (if I agreed with your answer I think it wouldnt solve my other problem). I will try to express you clearly what disturbs me here.

Comment: @StarBucK Okay, I answered the other question. I agree that there are multiple issues going on here.