# Quantization of a waveguide: he only has one of the two E.O.M in his Lagrangian. How can the quantization be correct?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, electric-circuits, inductance, waveguide

I am following [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4729) reference, appendinx C and D, around page 61

The goal is to quantize electric of current of propagating wave in a waveguide.

### Classical E.O.M:

We model a waveguide by a succession of LC oscillators:

[image]

We will study electric wave propagating on this line, thus we do a differential reasoning: $c_0$ is the capacitance per unit length, $l_0$ the inductance per unit length.

Using Kirchoff laws on an element of length $dx$, we then find the telegraph equations:

$$\partial_x V(x,t)=-l_0 \partial_t I(x,t) $$
$$\partial_x I(x,t)=-c_0 \partial_t V(x,t) $$

### Writing down Lagrangian and Hamiltonian:

We define the flux variable $\phi$ as:

$$ \phi(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^t V(x,t') dt'$$

Thus, we have by definition: $V(x,t)=\partial_t \phi(x,t)$

We also have: $I(x,t)=-\frac{1}{l_0} \partial_x \phi(x,t) $, it comes from the voltage drop around an inductance ($U=L \dot{I}$) and the fact $\phi$ is the time integral of $V$. (I can add precision if necessary).

Now, the author says that the Lagrangian density for our system is (I guess it is inspired from the Lagrangian of an LC oscillator):

$$\mathcal{L}(\dot{\phi},\partial_x \phi)=\frac{c}{2} \dot{\phi}^2-\frac{1}{2l}(\partial_x \phi)^2 $$

This Lagrangian leads to the following E.O.M:

$$\frac{1}{c_0 l_0}\partial_x^2 \phi - \partial_t^2 \phi=0 \Rightarrow \partial_x I(x,t)=-c_0 \partial_t V(x,t)$$

**We notice that this Lagrangian only implies one of the two E.O.M**

Then, he finds the momentum associated to $\phi$, he writes down the Hamiltonian, he imposes commutation relation between position and momentum to quantize the theory.

### My question

Here the Lagrangian density **only contains one of the two E.O.M of the system**. **Why is the quantization then correct**? For me you must have the full dynamic encoded in the Lagrangian then Hamiltonian to be able to quantize. How can the quantization then be correct? I am confused.

Comment: IMHO, you ask about two different approach for quantization: using hamiltonian vs using lagrangian, do not you?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov hmm actually the procedure (the only I know to be fair, and the one done in the reference), is to start from the lagrangian, find the conjugated momentum which tells us $[x,p]=i\hbar$. I guess it is what you would call lagrangian quantization ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions
$$V(x,t)=\partial_t \phi(x,t), \quad I(x,t)=-\frac{1}{l_0} \partial_x \phi(x,t) $$
automatically imply, by the equality of mixed partial derivatives ($\partial_x \partial_t \phi = \partial_t \partial_x \phi$), the result
$$\partial_x V = - \frac{1}{l_0} \partial_t I$$
which is your "missing" equation. This holds independent of the equations of motion.

This is not uncommon when formalizing things in Lagrangian mechanics. For example, the electromagnetic field strength can be defined as $F = dA$. In that case, the result $dF = 0$ follows by definition, independent of the equations of motion, and contains two of Maxwell's equations.

---

Edit: it seems the real question is, how can $I(x,t)=-\frac{1}{l_0} \partial_x \phi(x,t)$ be a definition when it is derived from Faraday's law? The point is that derivations in one context can be laws in another context, or postulates or definitions in yet another. Within the context of classical electromagnetism, starting from Maxwell's equations, this result is derived. But in the context of modeling a waveguide with an extremely simple Lagrangian, it must be a definition, because your Lagrangian doesn't even know what letter $I$ is or means. That's fine, because the two contexts are logically independent.

Comment: Well for me the only definition we have is the fact $\phi$ is the time integral of $V$. The link between $I$ and $\phi$ is not a definition, it is coming from a maxwell equation (the faraday one) that tells us this. So to find the dynamic we need another physical law than the one encoded by the E.O.M dictated by the Lagrangian. This is what disturbs me here.

Comment: @StarBucK The point is that the Lagrangian by itself doesn't know what the letters $V$, $I$, $\phi$, and so on _physically_ mean. I mean, this could just as easily be the Lagrangian for longitudinal waves in air, where $I$ is the mean air speed, $V$ is the pressure, and so on. They're just arbitrary letters.

Comment: @StarBucK Since we want $V$ and $I$ to physically represent voltage and current, we _define_ them in this formalism accordingly. There's nothing weird about this. It's just like how when you write down $F = ma$, you need to specify what $F$ and $m$ are to actually use it. The string of four characters "$F \ = \ m \ a$ is meaningless without that extra context.

Comment: For me it is not a problem of definition here. The only definition we have is the one relating $V$ and $\phi$. Because for me the explanation you give here would mean that the second telegraph equation that I lack is a definition of the intensity. It is not because I could totally imagine that the second telegraph equation that I "miss" here would be different.

Comment: @StarBucK If you forbid $I$ to be defined as I defined it, then how do you specify what $I$ is at all? That letter doesn't even appear in the Lagrangian. The Lagrangian by itself has no idea what $\phi$ physically represents, and it doesn't know Maxwell's equations -- it's just a string of about 10 characters. You have to specify the physical meaning yourself. That's just how physics is always done.

Comment: Hmmm right, I see what you mean but what still confuses me is that to obtain the second equation, what I physically did is to express the current in function of the flux (let's assume that by definition of the inductance we have $\Phi=L*I$), so at this point it is a matter of definition. **But** to related the flux to the voltage drop, I use the Faraday law which comes from physics. So at the same time I agree I don't know how to answer your question, but on another hand in this reasoning I needed to make use of one of the Maxwell law.

Comment: I cannot reconciliate the two contradictory visions. Because with the second vision it would mean at some point that you take the faraday law as a definition. Which is not, it is really a law that relates two different physical quantities.

Comment: @StarBucK Things that are laws in one context can be derived in another context, and definitions in yet another context.

Comment: @StarBucK When we do this Lagrangian formalism, we're starting over from scratch, because the formalism must be self-contained. So we need to put in appropriate definitions. The definitions we choose (including the definition of the Lagrangian itself) are motivated by things we observe in the physical world. If you applied different definitions, the formalism would still work, it just wouldn't produce useful results.

Comment: Would you agree with the following: If I wanted to write down the Lagrangian involing all physical quantities possible (like charge, magnetic field, etc), indeed I would lack this other equation of motion. But here, I am restricted to study only a subset of all the physical quantities that exists. So in this restricted context I can take the second equation as a **definition** of what I call "current".

Comment: @StarBucK Sure, but the real point is that you have to define all the letters you use. Yes, in a more complete Lagrangian, you wouldn't need to define $I$ in the way we did here. Instead, you could define the letter $I$ as, say, $dQ/dt$. But you still need to specify that the letter $Q$ (which presumably appears in the Lagrangian) _means_ the electric charge.

Comment: In another context involving more physical quantities (like if I wanted to relate electricity variable with electric/magnetic field), maybe I couldn't consider it as a definition of current anymore because I would have another definition of current coming from those extra variables. So this other equation of motion would then become a real equation of motion.

Comment: @StarBucK Perhaps a general way to sum up the lesson here is that whenever you have a self-contained formalism, everything of interest in that formalism should be defined. And defined no more than once.

Comment: @StarBucK It's completely acceptable to have the same letter have different definitions in two _different_ formalisms. That's not logically inconsistent because the formalisms are in principle logically independent.

Comment: Yeah it clarifies things for me. Indeed in this formalism I need to define $I$ at some point. I can choose to define it via $I=-\frac{1}{l_0}\partial_x \phi$, and then the other E.O.M is deduced from this definition without requiring any extra physical law. Thank you. I actually think this also answered my other question (but I will make sure of it)

Comment: Maybe it could be nice if you can summarize this in your answer because it is really what caused me the problem here. Or I can add an extra answer myself involving this discussion.